# Arrays assignment in C

Tags: c, arrays, double

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{

    double roomdata[5][18][2],t;

    scanf(" %lf",t);
    roomdata[0] = t; // How Come this does not work?
                     // I get a error "Incompatible Types in Assignment"
                     // but both roomdata array and t are same type of double.
}
```

I am trying to assign a value to the array `roomdata` at index [0] but every time I try I get a error saying its a *Incompatible Types in Assignment*, but I have both initialized as doubles? I'm guessing it has something to do with it being a 3d array but I am not sure.

Comment: You have a 3D array. Index [0] is a 2D array. Probably you need [0][0][0]

Comment: I tried that but that would just change the value of the index [0][0][0] not the one at index [0]

Comment: @user2671024 You simply can't do that. In C, arrays are not assignable.

Comment: @user2671024 Do you mean you want to assign t to all the elements which have first index 0? You can do it through a loop. Otherwise yes, the types are different double and double[][] are two different types.

Comment: If below answers do not answer your question, please clarify. Like, to make it really concrete, imagine a 5x18x2 stack of boxes (that is 180 boxes total) containging pieces of paper for writing numbers in them. Then explain, what number do you want to write to which pieces of paper. Set all to `t`, probably not?

Answer (score 4):

It should be

```
scanf(" %lf", &t);
roomdata[0][0][0] = t;
```

Answer (score 2):

You should pass address in scanf

```
scanf(" %lf",t);  ==> scanf(" %lf",&t);
             ^                     ^
```

And you should use proper index

```
roomdata[i][j][k] = t;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have misunderstood how arrays work. Do you want a single array with three values instead?

```
double roomdata[3], t;
roomdata[0] = 5;
roomdata[1] = 18;
roomdata[2] = 2;
scanf(" %1f", &t);
roomdata[0] = t;
```

Answer (score 0):

In the comment you say *"roomdata array and t are same type of double"*, and this is where you go wrong. They are not same type. `roomdata[0]` is array of arrays of doubles, while `t` is just double.

To avoid confusion, you should not define different types of variables in same statement like that, even though the language allows it. Insead use two statements:

```
double roomdata[5][18][2];
double t;
```

---

Additionally, in C it is not possible to assign to an array. In other words, this would not compile either, even though types do match: `roomdata[0] = roomdata[1];`

You can only assign to a single array element, which means you have to give all indexes. So in your question code, you may want this:

```
roomdata[0][0][0] = t;
```

If you want to "assign" arrays in C, you typically use [`memcpy`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/memcpy) or create your own (possibly nested) `for` loops, or wrap the array in a `struct` (because in C you can assign structs). Example, about `for` loop: if you want to assign `t` to a "layer" `roomdata[0][][]`, this is how:

```
int j, k;
for (j=0; j<18; ++j) {
    for(k=0; k<2; ++k) {
        roomdata[0][j][k] = t;
    }
}
```

---

Also, while you do not ask about it, `scanf(" %lf",t);` is wrong, you must pass pointer to the location where you want to store the value `scanf` reads. Additionally, you should always check the return value of `scanf`, or at least print it so you can notice a problem (read the Return Value section of [here](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf)). So that should be

```
double t = 0.0; // initialize with a know value in case scanf fails
int scannedCount = scanf(" %lf", &t);
printf("(scanf returned %d, value of t=%f)\n", scannedCount, t);
```

---

And while `roomdata` sounds like you indeed intend it to be a 3-dimensional grid of room contents, just in case: If you actually intended to have 1-dimensional double array with initial values 5, 2, 18, then you would do it like this:

```
// initialize with 3 elements, array length is automatically set to 3
double roomdata[] = { 5, 2, 18 };
```